# "Indirect question" is closed as not a real question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802022/length-of-vendor-and-advertising-identifiers) is an old question of mine. It has been closed as not a real question. I can understand the reason. Before closing the title of the question was "Length of Vendor and Advertising identifiers" and in the text part I was only saying that "I couldn't find the length of ...". I thought it was clear what I was asking. And it appears that it wasn't. Anyhow I have edited the question after that. Make the question pretty obvious. And it is still closed. What should I do? I have got an answer for that question long ago but it still bothers me having that closed.

Comment: You edited that question 20 minutes ago, it probably sits in the re-open queue. ... not anymore ...

Comment: Voted to re-open. Sorry, I didn't get the notification for your comment saying you'd updated the question. My Stack Overflow inbox overfloweth with hundreds of messages per day, and I can't keep up, so I don't even bother anymore.